# syntax highlight richedit control not working poperly

Tags: c++, winapi, richedit

I am trying to implement a syntax highlight editor with a richedit, it has works well with the current selected line, but I may be missing something. The CRichEdit is my own wrapper implementation of the richedit controller, the problem seems that the text is not selected properly even though I made sure the selected range generated with the code were what I get with the EM_EXGETSEL message.
The selection seems increasing 1 as the lines goes down, so I decided to ed_source.sendMessage(EM_LINEFROMCHAR, pos, 0) to the range which partially fix the problem except for some few lines where the coloring seems some time one or to position before and the real appropriate, so that is why I thing I may not be understanding something.

```
void parse(WIN::CRichEdit &ed_source, bool curseline)
{
    int pos, offset = 0;
    char delimiter[]={" \n\r(){};"}, *tok, *start;
    CStringA s;
    CString text;
    CWnd api;

    if(curseline){      
        ed_source.getLine(ed_source.getRow() - 1, text);
        offset = ed_source.sendMessage(EM_LINEINDEX, -1, 0);
    }else{
        text = ed_source.getCaption();
    }

    s = text;
    start = s.c_str();
    if(!start) return;

    tok = strtok(s.c_str(), delimiter);

    CHARRANGE cr = ed_source.getSelecteRange();
    ed_source.sendMessage(EM_HIDESELECTION, 1, 0) ;
    CHARRANGE range;
    while(tok)
    {
        int len = strlen(tok);

        pos = (tok - start);
        int x = ed_source.sendMessage(EM_LINEFROMCHAR, pos, 0);
        range.cpMin = offset + pos - x;
        range.cpMax = range.cpMin + len;

        ed_source.selectRange(range);
        if(isReserved(tok)){

            ed_source.setTextStyle(true, false);
            ed_source.setTextColor(keyboardColor);
        }else
            if(isType(tok)){
                ed_source.setTextStyle(false, false);
                ed_source.setTextColor(typeColor);
            }else {
                ed_source.setTextStyle(false, true);
                ed_source.setTextColor(textColor);
            }
        tok = strtok(0, delimiter);
    }

    ed_source.sendMessage(EM_HIDESELECTION, 0, 0) ;
    ed_source.selectRange(cr);
}
```

just to be more specific the moment I call the above function is immediately after loading the text on it. I assumed you may want to see the implementation of some of the above functions so here they are.

```
CHARRANGE CRichEdit::getSelecteRange()
{
    CHARRANGE crg = {0} ;
    sendMessage(EM_EXGETSEL, 0, (LPARAM)&crg);
    return crg;
}

void CRichEdit::selectRange(const CHARRANGE &cr)
{
    sendMessage( EM_EXSETSEL, 0, (LPARAM) &cr);
}


void CRichEdit::setTextColor(COLORREF col)
{ 
    CHARFORMAT format;
    memset(&format, 0, sizeof(CHARFORMAT));
    format.cbSize       = sizeof(CHARFORMAT);
    format.dwMask       = CFM_COLOR;
    format.crTextColor  = col;

    sendMessage( EM_SETCHARFORMAT, SCF_SELECTION, (LPARAM) &format);
}
```

Comment: Syntax highlighting in an editor on top of richedit control will never work. You'll be forever going back over text that you already formatted, and re-doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this article for some ideas:

Faster rich edit syntax highlighting
http://bcbjournal.org/articles/vol3/9910/Faster_rich_edit_syntax_highlighting.htm

It was written for the `TRichEdit` control in C++Builder, but the majority of the tips in it use straight Win32 API calls, and the few places that use VCL idioms can be easily adapted into Win32 equivilents.

**Update:** Try removing `EM_LINEFROMCHAR` from your loop.  `offset + pos` is already an absolute character position within the RichEdit, there should be no need to adjust it on each loop iteration.  If you really want to take line indexes into account then you should be looping through the lines one row at a time parsing each row individually, not parsing the entire content as a single string.  Try something more like this instead:

```
void parse(WIN::CRichEdit &ed_source, bool curseline)
{
    int startLine, endLine, offset;
    const char* delimiters = " \n\r(){};";
    char *tok, *start;
    CStringA s;
    CWnd api;

    if (curseline)
    {
        startLine = ed_source.getRow() - 1;
        endLine = startLine + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        startLine = 0;
        endLine = ed_source.sendMessage(EM_GETLINECOUNT, 0, 0);
    }

    CHARRANGE cr = ed_source.getSelecteRange();

    int eventMask = ed_source.SendMessage(EM_SETEVENTMASK, 0, 0);
    ed_source.SendMessage(WM_SETREDRAW, FALSE, 0);

    for (int line = startLine; line < endLine; ++line)
    {
        CString text;
        ed_source.getLine(line, text);

        s = text;
        start = s.c_str();
        if (!start) continue;

        offset = ed_source.sendMessage(EM_LINEINDEX, line, 0);

        tok = strtok(start, delimiters);
        while (tok)
        {
            CHARRANGE range;
            range.cpMin = offset + (int)(tok - start);
            range.cpMax = range.cpMin + strlen(tok);

            ed_source.selectRange(range);
            if (isReserved(tok))
            {
                ed_source.setTextStyle(true, false);
                ed_source.setTextColor(keyboardColor);
            }
            else if (isType(tok))
            {
                ed_source.setTextStyle(false, false);
                ed_source.setTextColor(typeColor);
            }
            else
            {
                ed_source.setTextStyle(false, true);
                ed_source.setTextColor(textColor);
            }

            tok = strtok(0, delimiters);
        }
    }

    ed_source.SendMessage(WM_SETREDRAW, TRUE, 0);
    ed_source.Invalidate(); // whatever your wrapper does to call ::InvalidateRect()

    ed_source.SendMessage(EM_SETEVENTMASK, 0, eventMask);

    ed_source.selectRange(cr);
}
```

With that said, instead of using `getLine()` and `strtok()` to parse text, you might consider using `EM_FINDWORDBREAK` to locate words and `EM_EXSETSEL`/`EM_GETSELTEXT` to retreive the characters of each word.  That way, you are using less memory and letting the RichEdit do more of the searching for you.  You can use `EM_SETWORDBREAKPROC/EX` if you want to customize the word delimiters searched for.

Comment: I took a look at it but, I wasn't able to see the part I am not understanding. In any case most of my code is working. For example when I am modifying only one line(which is when I call parse with curseline=true) the color is apply correctly. but when I make it false meaning I want to color every line is that the selection seems off a bit.

Comment: My first attempt was without the EM_LINEFROMCHAR since it supposed to be absolute position as you mentioned but noticed it was colorizing one increasing char index ahead as the line number increase. Reading it line by line as you said works well except that it left out lines of text a little more beyond the visible lines.

Comment: what do you mean by "it left out lines of text a little more beyond the visible lines"?

Comment: Well while scroll down I saw there were lines with no colors like it didn't update those.

Comment: From the text I have (which is a fragment shader code) from line 27 and down it starts leaving the text with not color.

Comment: To be more specific my richedit's height is 262 with a textsize of 14. It looks to me like the RichEdit does not update text a little more that the visible lines, maybe I get better result using the find function instead.

Comment: Sorry, can't answer that, as you did not provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) demonstrating when/where/how `parse()` is called.

Comment: I am alright with the help you gave me already, and I called the function immediately after copying the text to the RichEdit with this lines of code "m_vshader.ed_source.openFile(FullPathName);
 parse(m_vshader.ed_source, false);"

Comment: I found the issue. I had a bug on my getLine more precisely when getting the length of the line of text. It works fine now, but I am more interested on getting the whole text so I can do a better parsing of the text and like multiple line comment coloring, which I am not sure I can do with EM_FINDWORDBREAK yet, but I will read more about it.